# How to add current state to history by script?

Tags: scripting

I'd like to know how can I add current blender state to history stack over script? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its functionality is limited, but [`bpy.ops.ed.undo_push()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.ops.ed.html#bpy.ops.ed.undo_push) may give you close to what you're looking for.